# Calling a method from client to server (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, meteor

Client Side

```
Users = new Mongo.Collection("user-info");
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    var myApp = angular.module('calorie-counter', ['angular-meteor']);
    myApp.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.user = {
            item1: 0,
            item2: 0
        };

        $scope.submit = function () {
            Meteor.call("submit" ($scope.user));
        }
    }]);
}
```

Server side:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        submit: function (user) {
            Users.insert(user);
        }
    });
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is when the user clicks on the submit button on the client side, I want it to call a server side method where the information that the User entered will be saved into the collection. I'm passing in the `$scope.user` as a parameter (not too sure if I'm calling the method correctly) but the error I keep receiving is "submit is not a function". Initially, I was just inserting the `$scope.user` directly from that function, but I thought that type of an operation might be more suitable for the server side? (I'm not too sure if I'm thinking of this right or just overthinking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `,` after method name to pass parameters

```
Meteor.call("submit", $scope.user);
//           ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
//           Method   Parameter
```

[**Documentation**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call)

**Example**

For multiple parameters, use comma-separator between parameters

```
// sync call
var result = Meteor.call('foo', 1, 2);
```

Also, all the database operations should be done on Server side for security. Otherwise end users(*hackers*) can gain the access to database and can attack on your DB.

Make sure you move all the database handling code on server and remove the package named `insecure`. This is the package that allow you to access DB from client-side.

Comment: Ah! I should be like one answer at a time. LoL. I started writing the answer and didn't post! `:(`

Comment: Oh shoot, I thought my syntax looked sketchy. Thanks! I'm a little confused in terms of determining if a method should be on the client block vs the server block. Do you think having this type of a function that adds something to the database be on the server side or client side? Because I can do the same very easily on the client side, I just thought it was an operation more meant for the server side.

Comment: @halapgos1 All the database operations should be done on server side. Otherwise, client can access DB which is security risk. Also, remove the package called `insecure`. This is the package that allow you to access DB from client side

Comment: @Tushar Oh shoot, my bad. Don't worry, I gotcha!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a valid syntax:

```
Meteor.call("submit"($scope.user));
```

You need to pass it as a parameter. Please change it to:

```
Meteor.call("submit", $scope.user);
```

Comment: Oh shoot, I thought my syntax looked sketchy. Thanks! I'm a little confused in terms of determining if a method should be on the client block vs the server block. Do you think having this type of a function that adds something to the database be on the server side or client side? Because I can do the same very easily on the client side, I just thought it was an operation more meant for the server side.